# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el cuerpo de una petición? C

Tags: c, post, http

¿Sabéis como puedo obtener el cuerpo de una petición POST (HTTP 1.1)? Necesito conseguir los parámetros que me pasan con la petición.

Este sería el tipo de consultas que recibiría:

```
POST /bin/login HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login.html
Accept-Language: en-us
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Content-Length: 37
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

User=Peter+Lee&pw=123456&action=login
```

Hasta ahora he estado utilizando la librería [picohttpparse](https://github.com/h2o/picohttpparser) para obtener la petición pero no encuentro la manera de obtener el `body`.

Aquí el código que llevo hasta ahora:

```
while(1){

    while ((rret = recv(connfd, buf + buflen, sizeof(buf) - buflen, 0)) == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (rret <= 0){
        printf("IOError\n");
        return -1;
    }
    prevbuflen = buflen;
    buflen += rret;
    /* parse the request */
    num_headers = sizeof(headers) / sizeof(headers[0]);
    pret = phr_parse_request(buf, buflen, &method, &method_len, &path, &path_len,
                             &minor_version, headers, &num_headers, prevbuflen);
    if (pret > 0){
        break; /* successfully parsed the request */
    }
    else if (pret == -1){
        printf("ParseError\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* request is incomplete, continue the loop */
    assert(pret == -2);
    if (buflen == sizeof(buf)){
        printf("RequestIsTooLongError\n");
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿ Podrías poner un ejemplo con los datos que estás recibiendo ?

Comment: @Trauma POST /bin/login HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login.html
Accept-Language: en-us
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Content-Length: 37
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
   
User=Peter+Lee&pw=123456&action=login

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir la nueva información... también sería deseable que publicases qué has intentado hasta ahora

Comment: @eferion Listo. Perdón por las molestias, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: No es necesario que te disculpes. Te estaba informando porque he visto que eres nuevo. Piensa que si las preguntas no cumplen unos requisitos mínimos no solo será más difícil que obtengas respuesta sino que es hasta posible que la pregunta acabe cerrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes toda la información que necesitas en la cabecera:

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   ...
>   Content-Length: 37

Solo con eso, ya sabemos que la longitud de los datos *extra* (los que quieres obtener) es de 37 bytes. Además, ya sabemos *que* son y como interpretarlos; en la [página de la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) obtenemos mas info:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded: Los valores son codificados en tuplas de valores llaves separados por '&', con un '='  entre la llave y el valor. Caracteres no-Alfanumericos son percent encoded

Y, si nos fijamos en los datos que siguen a las cabeceras ...

> User=Peter+Lee&pw=123456&action=login

vemos que ocupan exactamente 37 bytes, justo lo que estabamos esperando.

Y, si los *urldecodeamos*, viene a ser

> User=Peter Lee
>   pw=123456
>   action=login

Como último punto, tenemos la separación entre *headers* y *body*; el estándar dicta que sea una cadena `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Gracias por la info! Lo intentaré ahora.